# How to send request in Python

Tags: python, request

I am trying to understand how this string ?user=username&password=password&version=13 could be converted to a GET or POST request i don't have lot of experience with requests so be sorry if i said something wrong

EDIT

As Lennart Regebro i installed requests package and i resolved my problem with this simple string :

> > > r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get", 
> > >       ...      params={'user': 'username', 'password': 'password', 'version': '13'})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a library to make requests. The ones in the standard library are called [`urllib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) and [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) in Python 2, [`urllib.request`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) in Python 3.

However, an even better one is the third-party library [`requests`](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). With requests you would do it this way:

```
>>> r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get", 
...      params={'user': 'username', 'password': 'password', 'version': '13'})
```

Comment: is there any method i can do it with socket?

Comment: @user3104766 Yes, you can write your own library if you want to.

Comment: and just another question , if i use for example s.connect("www.example.com") and i want to finish this url like www.example.com/?user=example&password=example&version=13 what should i do with urllib (or request) ?

Comment: @user3104766 You shouldn't. Both urllib and request will do the socket handling for you, and they will do it better than you do. You want to open a URL and make a request. For that you use urllib or urllib2, or urllib.request or requests. You do *not* use sockets, unless you are implementing your own requests library, which you aren't.

Comment: so i can just (using requests) write  r = requests.get('www.example.com/?user=123&password=123&version=13')

Comment: @user3104766 Yup. Although there is a better way for requests, I'll add it.

Comment: Are there any method to install requests in windows?

Comment: @user3104766 Are you asking how to install Python modules in Windows, or do you have a specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

```
>>> from urllib import urlencode
>>> s = {'user': 'fsp', 'pass': 'root'}
>>> urlencode(s)
'user=fsp&pass=root'
```

then:

```
path = path + '?' + urllib.urlencode(kwargs)
```

Finally:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlopen(path)
```

Better try requests.